# Javascript Pong Game Moving Bats

Tags: javascript, onkeypress, pong

I'm currently on a Pong game tutorial, with Javascript. I'm at the point where I need to make the 2 bats move, by pressing certain keys. The bats should move when I press K, M, A or Z. But they are not moving at all. My IDE says 'variable e hides argument'.
This is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
batupdate = function(e) {   
var e = window.event ? event : e;

if (e.keyCode) 
{ 
    key = e.keyCode; 
}

else if (typeof (e.which) != 'undefined') 
{ 
    key = e.which; 
}

switch (key) 
{
    case (122):
        BatL.move(1);
        break;
    case (97):
        BatL.move(-1);
        break;
    case (107):
        BatR.move(-1);
        break;
    case (109):
        BatR.move(1);
        break;
}
}

document.onkeypress = batupdate;
```

Comment: In your second line -- `var e = ...`. You'll never be able to use the `e` you pass in via `function(e)`.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I thought that was possibly it too, but then I tried it and it actually worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem doesn't lie in the code you have shown us. You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/K6MRu/

I took out the `Bat[LR].move()` calls because we don't have their implementation and replaced them with alerts showing the same data. You'll see that it it works just fine. This means the problems has to be in the value of the `BatL` and/or `BatR` variables or the implementation of the `move()` function.

The message your IDE is giving is not actually a problem at all, as it just means you can't access something you aren't trying to access. You can make the message go away by removing the `var` in `var e = window.event ? event : e;` as others have suggested and I would recommend doing so, but it won't solve the problem of your bats not moving.

Comment: The error was in my move function. I should have checked everything better. Thank you very much. It's for my school and I was stuck for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

Change `var e = ...` in line 2 to `e = ...`

Try splitting up the problem by putting a breakpoint on `switch (key)` and looking at `key` and `e`, or writing `console.log("E: " + e + " KEY: " + key)` if you are not familiar with your debugger yet.

I'm not sure if it's necessary - probably not - but I'm paranoid about these things, so to be on the safe side I'd push the `else if` back to not have a new line between it and the `if` statement it's connected to.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but this has no effect.

Comment: How can I check this. I'm a beginner btw.

Comment: I write console.log("E: " + e + " KEY: " + key); in my code, but nothing happens when I run it. (I'm using Netbeans)

Comment: I don't know about netbeans, but open the page in your browser, open your console (use Google to find out where it is) and you should see something unless the code is breaking before it gets there in which case the console should inform you about that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a variable e with the code:

```
var e = window.event ? event : e ;
```

Which exists in the batupdate function's scope. You are also passing a parameter into that function with is labelled e.

Basically you are using the same name for 2 different things, which is problematic. Try this instead:

```
e = window.event ? event : e ;
```

Comment: This shouldn't be causing any problems

Comment: I disagree, the error pretty clearly says it's the problem. "Variable e hides argument". He's creating a variable named e which is hiding the argument, named e.

Comment: How should I do this? I'm following a tutorial and there's no help or whatsoever on that website. It just gives this code, without further explanation on what 'e' does.

Comment: Then you're mistaken. I took this code: `function b(a) { var a = a; alert(a); } b('b')` and executed in Firefox, Internet Explorer and Chrome and each time it alerted 'b'. The warning from the IDE was that later on in the function, you couldn't use the original `e`, but we're not trying to do so, so it shouldn't be causing any problems at all.

Comment: Have another look at my answer. You should be able to reassign e without declaring it as a new variable. It already exists in the scope of the function.

Comment: @Jasper I think you need to read the original question again. While it runs fine in the browser, the original post says his IDE is giving him the message. If I'm mistake, can you suggest what is causing this message?

Comment: You might need to do the re-reading: it is *not* running fine in the browser, the bats aren't moving. Trying to be complete, he also gave us the message the IDE was giving, which you resolve, but that still leaves the thing in a non-functional condition

Comment: You misunderstand. I was referring to your example.

Comment: In that case, he is getting that message, which he can indeed remove the way you say. However, my sample shows there is no effective difference between what his code does and what yours does, so your changes don't do anything beyond removing his message, which means it does not solve the problem the OP is having

Comment: Indeed, it's not changing anything. I can't seem to debug, only in my .php file, not in my .js file. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Removing the error is the first step to solving the problem. Thanks for creating an answer.